# How does the damage bonus of Tactical Cloak work with automatic weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

The Tactical Cloak power of the Infiltrator not only allows one to become invisible, but also provides a significant damage bonus:

[image]

I'm wondering now on which attacks the damage bonus when breaking cloak is applied. If I start firing with an assault rifle out of cloak does only the very first shot get a bonus, or do multiple shots benefit from it. How does it work with weapons that fire in bursts?

Depending on how this bonus exactly works it might be necessary to use high-damage/low rate of fire weapons to get a substantial benefit from this power. So I'm wondering if I need to change my weapon loadout to really take advantage of this power.

Comment: My assumption is that you would get the bonus for one trigger pull, or until the cloak breaks.  I'm not sure how anyone would go about verifying that.

Comment: Also note that for some weapons that can be charged, the cloak is broken and the bonus is applied when you _begin_ charging, so you can choose between cloaking before charging to get the damage bonus, or cloaking after you begin charging to charge while cloaked, but in that case you don't get the damage bonus.

Answer (score 2):

[I found this forum thread about ME2](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/128/index/1292055).  It says that the bonus lasts for 1 second.  My guess would be that it also holds true for ME3.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Multiplayer Strategy #2](http://www.masseffect.com/videos/video/e924dcdbf6c8051ea714168a69ca6d59) video the developer discusses the Infiltrator class and specifically mentions the bonus hanging around for a couple of seconds after the cloak exits (2:49-3:01 in the video)